# How to determine if tethered sump pump float switch is triggering at the right height?

Tags: switch, drainage, sump-pump, flooding

Yikes! It rained a ton yesterday and my basement flooded. Water soaking the floor. When I looked into the sump pump, it had lots of water in it. I pulled up on the float and it all emptied. As we continued to clean up, the sump pump basin filled again. I noticed that it never seemed to trigger the float switch. I started to suspect that the float switch was not calibrated correctly or it was broken.

Here's a drawing of my sump pump:

[image: drawing of sump pump setup]

There are ***two*** pipes connected to the side of the basin (is this atypical?). The lower PIPE #2 is approximately at the level of the top of the pump motor unit where the float is attached. At this water level, the float ***does not*** engage (upper red drawing). I am fairly convinced that the water is entering the basin via PIPE #2 (I never saw the water level significantly above the top of PIPE #2 or near PIPE #1).

To trigger the float switch I have to physically lift it up well above the water line (green) .

The [type of float](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/everbilt-tethered-float-switch/1001565927) is a bulb part with a cord attached to the top of the motor unit. It hangs to the side of the motor when there's no water (lower red drawing) and does float up with the water (upper red drawing), albeit without triggering at that level. It's not obvious me how to adjust this to a different trigger height if I wanted to. The bulb has some jangling thing inside which rolls toward the chord once the bulb part is nearly completely upside down (green).

How can I determine if my float is triggering at the right height?

If it's not at the right height, then are these types adjustable? (or should I switch it to this [vertical style](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/everbilt-vertical-float-switch/1001565926)?)

Comment: The float comes with the sump as a unit. I think the connection between the switch and the float is faulty.

Comment: You have basically two choices. Replace the pump or purchase a repair kit for the float. If you have never done anything like this or do not have somebody that can help you go back to the first choice and replace it. I believe you have an inline check in the outlet piping of the pump, best to replace that as well. When I changed my pump the check was glued a few inches above the pump so cut it off at that point and replaced it with one that has rubber tubing that just clamps to the plastic drain line, makes changing the pump a simple job with a screwdriver. Be sure orent the check correctly.

Comment: Is the bulb actually attached with a cord (flexible rope or string), or with a stiff metal rod? If it's a rod, you can put a "U" bend in it so the bulb sits in the upright trigger-the-pump-position when it's at the level you want it to start pumping. Cheaper than a repair kit or replacement and even if it goes wrong, you're back to repair kit or replacement.

Comment: It's a flexible cord. It doesn't hold a shape if I bend it. I thought about trying to tie it down lower but I can't physically reach down that low and I think I'd have to take the whole thing sump pump unit out, which starts to get beyond my handiness comfort level.

Comment: This is not an adjustment issue.  The most common cause is that the contact inside the bulb has worn out.  I have had several pumps with float switches similar to yours and the vertical rod types fail over the years.  Because of the waterproofing of the wiring, they cannot be readily repaired and I just have to replace the whole pump.

Comment: Thanks. But why replace the whole pump? Isn't this float part replaceable on its own?

Comment: iF you look at the end of the cord that connects the float to the pump you will see a waterproof seal.  If you look at the pump, you would have to take the pump apart to get to the terminals where the wires are connected.  THis would break the waterproof seal of the pump and you would also most likely destroy the waterproof connection where the wires enters the pump.   Waterproof pumps for home use are not normally designed to be repaired because you would not be able to make it waterproof.  You can validate this my calling the manufacture support line and asking them if it is repairable.

Comment: If the pump consistently turns on in that green position or near vertical, then the switch is working properly.  If you find that the sump basin is filling completely and the float is in the upper position, the pump is not running then the switch is bad.

Comment: The point about the seal makes sense. The second comment doesn't seem to cover all cases though. What if the water level is constantly filling to the level shown in the drawing but never _above_ PIPE 2. So the green position is never reached and the basin never empties. Is this a bad installation? A miscalibrated switch? What are these two pipes?

Comment: Your basement would still be dry because the level of the water in the basin is below the top of the basin.  Even from your diagram, you can see that the water in the basin will never go below pipe #2.  Don;t expect the pump to completely empty the basin.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's precisely my concern. I don't know if this setup is actually broken / the cause of my wet basement.